# Растягивается слайдер во flexbox контейнере

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Если поместить слайдер во `flexbox`-элемент, у которого задано свойство `flex-grow: 1`, слайдер неверно считает ширину и вылазит далеко за пределы элемента, даже если у родителя задана фиксированная ширина/высота.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content__photos {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.content__button {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.slider__slide {
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content__photos">
    <div class="slider content__slider swiper-container js-slider">
      <div class="slider__wrapper swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="slider__slide swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="slider__slide swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="slider__slide swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="slider__slide swiper-slide"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="button content__button">Button</button>
</div>
```

Пример: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cherniavsky94/pen/LgmQaZ)

Кто с этим сталкивался, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Приложите пример кода, чтобы пользователи могли наглядно видеть то, что вы имеете в виду. В таком случае шанс получить ответ увеличивается в разы.

Comment: А если добавить `overflow:hidden;` к `class="content"`

Comment: Тогда просто обрежется кнопка

Comment: Вы как-то решили проблему? У меня то же самое.

Comment: Ответил на вопрос

Answer (score 1):

В .content__photos добавить min-width: 0

```
.content__photos {
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
```